# How to determine if and which linux security module (LSM) is available?

Tags: virtual-machine, system-information, lsm

Is there a way to find out if and in case which linux security LSM (apparmor, selinux, grsecurity) is used by the kernel?

To be more specific let's assume I am a legimate root user of the machine?

If information available also it would be nice to furthermore know:
With regard to the question, is there a difference with considering the machine being (a) a local computer, (b) a dedicated server and (c) a virtual server "vServer"

### update

I know that I could for instance install the user-space stuff
(on a debian for instance `apt-get install apparmor`) and check if it yields
results related to the specific LSM. So I could do for apparmor
`sudo apparmor_status` which would then for instance yield:
`apparmor module is not loaded.` which helps me rule out that option. Yet I was looking for a more general approach covering most/all LSM.

### update2

I have discovered the path `/sys/kernel/security`. Maybe this is helpful finding an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can check `/sys/kernel/security` what's available.

See also dmesg or `/proc/cmdline` for boot settings.

If your `config.gz` available then

```
zgrep CONFIG_SECURITY /proc/config.gz
```

else

```
grep CONFIG_SECURITY /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! Good to get confirmation on the `/sys/kernel/security/` The other options have been quite interesting as well. .... my case is case (c) a vServer and there no LSM available and no `/proc/comdline` and no `dmesg` information. vServer seem to suck :(. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is search for built-in modules under `/sys/module`.

E.g., on Ubuntu 16.04 which has apparmor enabled, the following directory exists:

```
/sys/module/apparmor/
```

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system

Unfortunately, neither `ls /sys/kernel/security` or `ls /sys/module/` showed anything for `selinux` [on Android AOSP in QEMU](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48310014/10), which seems to have selinux, I wonder why.

If the kernel is build with SELinux, boot `dmesg` contains:

```
SELinux:  Initializing.
```